# Performance issue loop in all rows jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am facing a performance issue (slow and laggy) when the user clicks the save button its's will take around 10 seconds to load finish it. It's because that I have 150 selection boxes and I need to loop every single selection for validation. If the selection has a selected value then I will add it into an array.

Is there any way I can improve the validation in order to solve the performance issue?

[image]

**html**

```
    <table class="table table-bordered listable specialrow">
           <thead>
              <tr>name</tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             @for($i = 0; $i <= 149; $i++)
                <tr class="allrow" id="row_{{$i}}">
                   <td width="20%">
                    <select class="form-control select2 firstname v1" id="name1_{{$i}}" name="name[]" style="width: 100%;">
<option value="-1" selected="" disabled="">Please Select Name</option>
<option value="1">K-76</option>
</select>
    </td>
               </tr>
           @endfor
           </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Jquery save button**

```
 $('.savebtn').on('click', function() {
      var error1 = false;
        var finaldata2 = [];
        var sort       = 0;
      
      $('.listable .allrow').each(function(index, item) {

        //firstname(validation) (issue on this code) *if comment will fast*
        if ($(item).find($(".firstname option:selected")).val() == -1) {
          error1 = true;
        } else {
          error1 = false;
        }

        if (error1 == false) {
         
          finaldata2.push({
            "name": $(item).find($(".firstname")).val(),
            "sorting": sort,
          });
          sort++;
        }
        if (error1 == false) {
          combine.push("yes");
        }
      });

if(combine.length > 0 ){
  data: {
            "finaldata2":finaldata2
           },
}
    });
```

Comment: `I faced a performance issue` but what is the issue? Slow loading or ??

Comment: slow loading and lag

Comment: I would assume it's because you create quite a few unnecessary jQuery objects and don't cache them for later use. Can you add the relevant HTML (or at the very least a sample of it) to the question so we can create a working example to test performance.

Comment: where did you define finaldata2?

Comment: Hmm... if your having a perfomance problem iterating through your inputs I would suggest you create a state variable for each input. Whenever, there is a change in a input you run the validation for that single input. The form is only valid if all inputs are valid. With this approach you won't need to the loop through the rows anymore when you submit the form.

Comment: Hi, can provide some example ya? Really no idea about it